# Converter Html em Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, canvas

É possível converter uma página html em canvas? Por exemplo, tenho uma página contruída em html5 e queria que essa página fosse toda "minificada" para apenas uma tag  ?

Não quero que a página html seja transformado imagem.
Ps.: Pergunta a nível de conhecimento.

Answer (score 5):

Canvas não renderiza HTML, só "imagens". Existem algumas bibliotecas que podem tentar converter o HTML em imagens, tal como [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Entretanto, você pode criar um Web Component para ter "uma página em uma tag".

No exemplo abaixo, você pode ver três tecnologias trabalhando em conjunto:

1. **Templates**: define um trecho de HTML para ser reusado
2. **Custom Elements**: registra uma nova tag (elemento) e a forma como ele será renderizado
3. **Shadow DOM**: isola a árvore de elementos e os estilos que estão dentro de um elemento, no caso, o nosso componente

```js
document.registerElement('super-componente', { 
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
    createdCallback: {
      value: function() {
        var template = document.querySelector('#super-componente');
        console.log(template);
        var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
        this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<template id="super-componente">
  <style>
    * { color: red }
  </style>
  <div>
    <content></content>
  </div>
</template>

<h1>Minha página</h1>
<super-componente>
  <h2>Título 1</h2>
  <p>conteúdo 1</p>
</super-componente>
<super-componente>
  <h2>Título 2</h2>
  <p>conteúdo 2</p>
</super-componente>
```

Você pode inclusive deixar o componente em outro arquivo HTML e importá-lo em outras páginas assim:

```
<link rel="import" href="super-componente.html">
```

Veja [outro exemplo](https://github.com/utluiz/my-markdown/blob/master/preview-component.php) mais complexo de um componente web que criei por esses dias num arquivo separado:

```
<template id="mmd-preview-template">
    <style>
        @import url("<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); ?>css/editor-preview.css");
<?php if (file_exists(wp_get_theme()->get_template_directory() . '/mmd-preview-editor.css')) { ?>
        @import url("<?php echo wp_get_theme()->get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mmd-preview-editor.css");
<?php } ?>
    </style>
    <div class='mmd-preview-content prettyprint'></div>
</template>
<?php if (file_exists(wp_get_theme()->get_template_directory() . '/mmd-preview-editor.js')) { ?>
<script type="text/java" src=""<?php echo wp_get_theme()->get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mmd-preview-editor.js""></script>
<?php } ?>
<script>
    var mmd_template = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#mmd-preview-template');
    var mmdPreview = document.registerElement('mmd-preview', {
        prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
            createdCallback: {
                value: function() {
                    var root = this.createShadowRoot();
                    var clone = document.importNode(mmd_template.content, true);
                    root.appendChild(clone);
                }
            },
            content: {
                value: function() {
                    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.mmd-preview-content').innerHTML;
                }
            },
            update: {
                value: function(content) {
                    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.mmd-preview-content').innerHTML = content;
                    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('previewComponentUpdated', { detail: {
                        'element': this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.mmd-preview-content'),
                        'content': content
                    }}));
                    var changedElement = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.mmd-changed');
                    if (changedElement) {
                        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('previewComponentElementChanged', { detail: {
                            'element': changedElement
                        }}));
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: utluiz, fiz essa pergunta por que o Google utiliza isso na exibição de imagens dos locais do Google Maps.
Acesse este link e inspecione, por favor.https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Av.+Paulista,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP/@-23.563023,-46.65355,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1s20046681!2e1!3e10!6s%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2Fproxy%2FoT_qW23gpoFm03kOgUkE2Zp29dc8n54Ro0SOZhgKt2u7MxFvAQTRKNDkk8-53XySuCYPFJXcIRi4A5bI0mAw0fU4Hd8FnA%3Dw203-h152!7i3072!8i2304!4m2!3m1!1s0x94ce59c8da0aa315:0xd59f9431f2c9776a

Comment: @DavidDamasceno Não vejo nenhum elemento dentro do `<canvas>`. Entretanto, nada impede a página de colocar tags por cima do canvas através de posicionamento. Mas não está dentro, apenas sobrepondo visualmente,

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> </title>
</head> 
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" title="canvas" style="outline: 1px solid red;"></canvas>
<div style="background-color: red">teste</div>
<div style="background-color: green">teste</div>
<div style="background-color: blue">teste</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
document.body.onload = function(){ htmL() }

function htmL(){
html = document.documentElement

height = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight )
width  = Math.max( document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.offsetWidth, 
                       html.clientWidth, html.scrollWidth, html.offsetWidth )

html.setAttribute( 'xmlns', html.namespaceURI )
xhtml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( html )
concatnameSspace( xhtml, width, height )
}

function concatnameSspace( xhtml, width, height ){
svg = ''.concat( '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="', width, '" height="', height, '">', 
'<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">', xhtml, '</foreignObject></svg>' )
svgToimg( svg )
}

function svgToimg( svg ){
img = new Image()
img.onload = function(event){ imgTocanvas(event.target, event.target.naturalWidth, event.target.naturalHeight) }
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent( svg )
}

function imgTocanvas( img, width, height ) {
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
canvas.width  = 147 // width
canvas.height = 210 // height
context = canvas.getContext('2d')
context.drawImage( img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height )
}
</script>
```